# MySQL datamapper adapter is chaining queries instead of joining

Tags: mysql, ruby, datamapper

I'm using DataMapper (the ruby gem) as an ORM to a mysql database.  (dm-core 1.1.0, do-mysql-adapter 1.1.0, do_mysql 0.10.6)

I'm writing an application that has two tables: a log of disk usage over time, and a "current usage" table containing foreign keys with the "latest" disk usage for easy reference.  The DataMapper classes are `Quota` and `LatestQuota`, with a simple schema:

```
class Quota
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :unique_id, Serial, :key => true
  property :percentage, Integer
  ... (more properties)
end

class LatestQuota
  include DataMapper::Resource
  belongs_to :quota, :key => true
end
```

In my code I want to find all the entries in the LatestQuota table that correspond with a quota with a percentage higher than 95.  I'm using the following datamapper query:

```
quotas = LatestQuota.all(:quota => {:percentage.gte => threshold})
...later...
quotas.select{|q| some_boolean_function?(q)}
```

Whereas some_boolean_function is something that filters out the results in a manner that DataMapper can't know about, hence why I need to call ruby's select().

But it ends up calling the following SQL queries (reported from DM's debug output:)

```
SELECT `unique_id` FROM `quota` WHERE `percentage` >= 95
```

then later:

```
SELECT `quota_unique_id` FROM `latest_quota` 
WHERE `quota_unique_id` IN (52, 78, 82, 232, 313, 320…. all the unique id's from the above query...)
```

This is a ridiculously suboptimal query, so I think I'm doing something wrong.  The `quota` table has millions of records in it (historical data) versus the 15k or so records in `latest_quota`, and selecting all `quota` records first and then selecting `latest_quota` records out of the results is exactly the wrong way to do it.

What I would like it to do is something to the effect of:

```
SELECT q.* from quota q
INNER JOIN latest_quota lq
ON lq.quota_unique_id=q.unique_id
WHERE q.percentage >= 95;
```

Which takes .01 seconds with my current data, instead of the 5 minutes or so it takes DataMapper to do its query.  Any way to coerce it to do what I want?  Do I have my relations wrong?  Am I querying it wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For some reason nested-Hash-style queries will always perform sub-selects. To force INNER JOINs, use String query-paths: LatestQuota.all('quota.percentage.gte' => threshold)

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed!  I'm wondering why I can't find any similar syntax in the docs...